# JQGrid not working

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid, xampp

NO grid appears after completing install. I have checked all  and , all link are good. I have install of the files need per WIKI. Has any one has issue or success will using XAMPP? I get a blank screen when i go to my website page. 
I am using json data and i have check to make sure that too is valid and it is.
HELP!

```
<link href="jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/ui.multiselect.css" />





<style>
    html, body {
        margin: 0;          /* Remove body margin/padding */
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;   /* Remove scroll bars on browser window */  
        font-size: 75%;
    }
    /*Splitter style */


    #LeftPane {
        /* optional, initial splitbar position */
        overflow: auto;
    }
    /*
     * Right-side element of the splitter.
    */

    #RightPane {
        padding: 2px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .ui-tabs-nav li {position: relative;}
    .ui-tabs-selected a span {padding-right: 10px;}
    .ui-tabs-close {display: none;position: absolute;top: 3px;right: 0px;z-index: 800;width: 16px;height: 14px;font-size: 10px; font-style: normal;cursor: pointer;}
    .ui-tabs-selected .ui-tabs-close {display: block;}
    .ui-layout-west .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td { border-bottom: 0px none;}
    .ui-datepicker {z-index:1200;}
    .rotate
        {
            /* for Safari */
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

            /* for Firefox */
            -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

            /* for Internet Explorer */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
        }

</style>

<script src="jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
    $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
</script>

<script src="js/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tablednd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.contextmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid(
    {       
      url:'jqgridExample.php',
        datatype: "json",
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes', 'test'],
    colModel:[
                        {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
                        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90},
                        {name:'name',index:'name asc, invdate', width:100},
                        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right"},
                        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right"},      
                        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right"},       
                        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
                     ],
   jsonReader : 
   {                     
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pager2',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"JSON Example"
  },
    });
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
</script>

<html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
    <table id="list2"></table>
    <div id="pager2"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are using Firefox, please install (if you haven't already) firebug and check if you get any error on console?

Answer (score 0):

At least two very important error one can see in the code which you posted. The first one: you included **multiple times** different versions of the same JavaScript. It is wrong. For example both lines

```
<script src="jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

insert jQuery. Both next lines

```
<script src="jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

insert jQuery UI. The lines

```
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

inserts `grid.locale-en.js`. The main modules of jqGrid will be inserted also twice with

```
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You should understand that depend from the implementation of every JavaScript module which you included you can have either only the first version of module working, only the second version of non-working mix from two version of the same modules. So you should include **every JavaScript module only once**.

The next problem is that **you included options of jqGrid in the wrong place**. Instead of

```
jsonReader : 
{                     
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pager2',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
   caption:"JSON Example"
},
```

you should use

```
jsonReader : {},
rowNum:10,
rowList:[10,20,30],
pager: '#pager2',
sortname: 'id',
viewrecords: true,
sortorder: "desc",
caption:"JSON Example"
```

where the value of `jsonReader` you should specify corresponds the format of JSON data which will be returned from the server (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data)).